# How to create a MACRO to create a JSON file from dataset

Tags: sas

I have some problems when I'm trying to generate a JSON file from dataset on SAS GUIDE. I generated a TEST.JSON:

```
{"TP_SMS":"1"  "NM_REMETENTESMS":"00000159"},
{"TP_SMS":"2"  "NM_REMETENTESMS":"00000159"},
{"TP_SMS":"3"  "NM_REMETENTESMS":"00000159"},
{"TP_SMS":"4"  "NM_REMETENTESMS":"00000159"},
{"TP_SMS":"5"  "NM_REMETENTESMS":"00000159"},
.
.
.
{"TP_SMS":"9"  "NM_REMETENTESMS":"00000159"},
```

The field TP_SMS is filled correct, but the second field is wrong - they are considering just the last position from my table.

Below there is my code white macro:

```
 data teste30; 
 set MATABLES.EXIT_DATA;
 RESP=cat(CD_CLIENTE,"|",ANWER_DATA);
 ID=_N_;
 call symputx('ID',ID);
 call symputx('CD_CLIENTE',CD_CLIENTE);
 call symputx('NM_PRIMNOMECLIENTE',NM_PRIMNOMECLIENTE);
 call symputx('RESP',RESP);
 call symputx('msgtext',msgtext);
run;    



 %macro MontaJSON(ID);
 WRITE OPEN OBJECT;
    WRITE VALUES "TP_SMS" "&ID"; 
    WRITE VALUES "NM_REMETENTESMS" "&CD_CLIENTE";
 WRITE CLOSE;
 %mend MontaJSON(ID);

%macro SMSRecords;
   %do i = 1 %to &dim_IDs;
   %MontaJSON(&&&ID_&i);
%end;
%mend SMSRecords;


proc sql;
select id, CD_CLIENTE into :ID_1 - :ID_&SysMaxLong from work.teste30;
%let dim_IDs = &sqlObs;
quit;



proc json out="C:\TEMP\TEST.json" pretty nokeys nosastags;
    write open array; /* container for all the data */
    %SMSRecords;
    write close;    /* container for all the data */
run;
```

I expect this macro get all datas on sequence, as TP_SMS code:

```
{"TP_SMS":"1"  "NM_REMETENTESMS":"00014578"},
{"TP_SMS":"2"  "NM_REMETENTESMS":"21323445"},
{"TP_SMS":"3"  "NM_REMETENTESMS":"23456753"},
{"TP_SMS":"4"  "NM_REMETENTESMS":"00457663"},
{"TP_SMS":"5"  "NM_REMETENTESMS":"00014795"},
{"TP_SMS":"6"  "NM_REMETENTESMS":"00014566"},
{"TP_SMS":"7"  "NM_REMETENTESMS":"00014578"},
{"TP_SMS":"8"  "NM_REMETENTESMS":"00000122"},
{"TP_SMS":"9"  "NM_REMETENTESMS":"00000159"}
```

Does anyone has some idea to solve it?

Tks

Comment: Are you only exporting two fields in the whole file? If so, a data step would likely be much easier for this particular case.

Comment: That does not look like valid JSON.  Perhaps you are trying to create a JSONLines file instead?  But even in that format shouldn't there be a comma between the two fields? `{"TP_SMS":"1" ,"NM_REMETENTESMS":"00014578"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would avoid generating all of those macro variables that are confusing your code.

Instead for that simple format you can just write the file directly instead of using PROC JSON.

```
data _null_;
  set MATABLES.EXIT_DATA end=eof;
  file "C:\TEMP\TEST.json" ;
  if _n_=1 then put '[';
  if not eof then delim=',';
  put '{"TP_SMS":' id :$quote. ' "NM_REMETENTESMS":' CD_CLIENTE :$quote. '}' delim ;
  if eof then put ']';
run;
```

Or if you really find that PROC JSON helps then use a similar data step to write the lines of code and use %INCLUDE to run the generated code.

```
filename code temp;
data _null_;
  set MATABLES.EXIT_DATA ;
  file code ;
  put 'WRITE OPEN OBJECT;'
    / 'WRITE VALUES "TP_SMS" ' ID :$quote. ';' 
    / 'WRITE VALUES "NM_REMETENTESMS" ' CD_CLIENTE :$quote. ';'
    / 'WRITE CLOSE;'
  ;
run;
proc json out="C:\TEMP\TEST.json" pretty nokeys nosastags;
  write open array; /* container for all the data */
  %include code;
  write close;    /* container for all the data */
run;
```

Comment: Hi Tom, simple code solved my problem!  Tks a lot for your help!

Comment: just a quickly question:  In my file OUTI have a container for all data.  Is there any way to create this file outside a container?  Example:  { ...datas1...},{ ....datas2....},{...datas3...},{ ....datas_N_....}

Comment: The first code is manually adding square brackets so you can just not do that.  But without them what you have it NOT a valid JSON file.

Comment: I see, it is make sense! Thanks again Tom!

Answer (score 1):

This line is your problem, it will only hold the last data point.

```
  call symputx('CD_CLIENTE',CD_CLIENTE);
```

Instead, create a value for each ID, similar to how you created the IDs.

```
       call symputx(catx('_', 'CD_CLIENTE', put(i, 8.-l)), CD_CLIENTE);
```

Then use it later on as `&&&CD_CLIENTE&i`